# Retrieving the mobile number programmatically?

Tags: java, android-studio

```
public void get(View view) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // Permission is not granted
            phone.setText("Not granted");
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);

        }
        else {
            phone.setText("Granted");
            TelephonyManager mTelephonyMgr;
            mTelephonyMgr = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService
                    (Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);



       String number = mTelephonyMgr.getLine1Number();
        //String number = getMyPhoneNO();
        if (number.matches("")) {
            phone.setText("There is no number");
        }
        else {
            phone.setText(number);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please spend the 1 minute it takes to properly format your input. That preview window exists for a reason. And read [mcve] and enhance your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

try to mention the required permissions to read phone state in AndroidManifest.xml

For eg.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

This grants permission to your app that it can read state of your android phone

Comment: you can also refer      https://gist.github.com/ftvs/e61ccb039f511eb288ee

Comment: written the same permission in the manifest but it doesn't work